# Trying to link my user name input and menu to my game function in python hangman

Tags: python, function, user-input

I'm trying to link my ask_for_name() and menu() functions to my play() function but where
ever I place the function headings it doesn't seem to work or get called. The game starts up first and at the end of gameplay asks if you want to restart, yes or no, If you click no, it goes back to what I want at the beginning of my game, my user-input asking for name and the menu, press 1 to play the game and 2 for instructions. When I click 1 the game wont start and throws an error message, does anyone know what I'm missing here? I'm new to python and seem to keep going in circles with this problem, the code is mentioned below:

```
def ask_for_name():
while True:
    name = input(YELLOW_COLOR + "Please Enter Your Name:\n")
    
    if not name.isalpha():
        print("Name must be letters only\n")
    else:
        print(f"Hello {name}, Welcome to Chris's Hangman and Good Luck!\n")
        menu()
return name   


def menu():
"""
menu function which gives the user two options
- Press 1 to play or 2 for instructions
- only accepts valid keys or error message comes up
"""
while True:
    user_input = input("Press P to Play game\nPress I for Instructions\n").upper()
    if user_input == "P":
        play()
    elif user_input == "I":
        print(
            "1.The computer will generate a random word and it's\n"
            "your task to guess the letters from the word.\n"
            "2.To guess, type a letter of your choice and hit enter.\n"
            "3.If you guess correctly, the letter will be revealed.\n"
            "4.If you guess incorrectly, you will lose a life and \n"
            " the Hangman will start to appear.\n"
            "5.You have 8 lives to guess the correct word.\n"

            "Good Luck!\n")
        enter_input = input("Press Enter to go back to the menu\n").upper()
        if enter_input == "":
            menu()
        else:
            print(RED_COLOR + "Oops look's like you pressed the wrong key!\n")
            
    else:
        print("Invalid Character, please try again!\n")



        
word = "dog" #random.choice(WORDS)
word = word.upper()
reveal = list(len(word)*'_')
lives = 8
game_is_won = False

def check_letter(letter, word):
global reveal
for i in range(0,len(word)):
    letter = word[i]
    if guess == letter:
        reveal[i] = guess
if '_' not in reveal:
    return True
else:
    return False


def restart_game():
"""
Gives player option to restart, otherwise returns to menu
"""
game_restart = False

while not game_restart:
    restart = input("Would you like to play again?"
                    "Y/N").upper()
    try:
        if restart == "Y":
            game_restart = True

            play()

        elif restart == "N":
            game_restart = True
            print("\n")
            header()
            ask_for_name()
            menu()

        else:
            raise ValueError(
            "You must type in Y or N"
            )

    except ValueError as e:
        print("\n You must type in Y or N Please try again.\n")


def play():
os.system("clear")
header()
print(hangman[8-lives])
print(' '.join([str(e) for e in reveal]))
print(f"You have {lives} lives")


while game_is_won == False and lives > 0:
play()
guess = input('Guess a letter or an entire word:')
guess = guess.upper()

if guess == word:
    game_is_won = True
    reveal = word
elif len(guess) == 1 and guess in word:
    game_is_won = check_letter(guess, word)
else:
    lives -= 1

if game_is_won:
    player_won()
    print("WELL DONE")
    
else:
    player_lost()
    print(f"YOU FAILED the word was: {word}")
    

restart_game()
```

Comment: You need to share a minimal version of your code to allow the community to replicate your issue.  Trying out you code, there were missing functions that did not allow the program to be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there were portions of the game program missing, I filled in the missing bits with some placeholder functions.  After trying out the game and seeing where it appeared to get stuck, I made some tweaks to it to make it function in the spirit of a hangman game.  Following is the tweaked code for your analysis.

```
import os

word = "dog" #random.choice(WORDS)
word = word.upper()
reveal = list(len(word)*'_')
lives = 8
game_is_won = False
hangman = []            # Added this so as to make the game work - temporary

for g in range(0,8):
    hangman.append('-')

def header():
    return

def ask_for_name():
    while True:
        name = input("Please Enter Your Name:\n")
    
        if not name.isalpha():
            print("Name must be letters only\n")
        else:
            print(f"Hello {name}, Welcome to Chris's Hangman and Good Luck!\n")
            menu()
            break       # Added this to get out of the while loop
    return name   

def menu():
    
    while True:
        user_input = input("Press P to Play game\nPress I for Instructions\n").upper()
        if user_input == "P":
            lives = 8
            game_is_won = False
            break
        elif user_input == "I":
            print("1.The computer will generate a random word and it's\n"
                "your task to guess the letters from the word.\n"
                "2.To guess, type a letter of your choice and hit enter.\n"
                "3.If you guess correctly, the letter will be revealed.\n"
                "4.If you guess incorrectly, you will lose a life and \n"
                " the Hangman will start to appear.\n"
                "5.You have 8 lives to guess the correct word.\n"
  
                "Good Luck!\n")
            enter_input = input("Press Enter to go back to the menu\n").upper()
            if enter_input == "":
                pass
                #menu()
            else:
                print("Oops look's like you pressed the wrong key!\n")
            
        else:
            print("Invalid Character, please try again!\n")

def check_letter(guess, word):
    global reveal
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        letter = str(word[i])
        if guess == letter:
            reveal[i] = guess
    if '_' not in reveal:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def restart_game():         # Added return of decision
    """
    Gives player option to restart, otherwise returns to menu
    """
    game_restart = False

    while not game_restart:
        restart = input("Would you like to play again?" "Y/N/Q ").upper()   # Added a quit option
        try:
            if restart == "Y":
                return True

            elif restart == "N":
                game_restart = True
                print("\n")
                header()
                ask_for_name()
                #menu()
                return True
                
            elif restart == "Q":
                return False

            else:
                raise ValueError("You must type in Y or N")

        except ValueError as e:
            print("\n You must type in Y or N Please try again.\n")
            
def player_won():       # Added this to make the game work
    print("Yea!")
    return
    
def player_lost():      # Added this to make the game work
    print("Boohoo")
    return

def play():
    os.system("clear")
    header()
    print(hangman[8-lives])
    print(' '.join([str(e) for e in reveal]))
    print(f"You have {lives} lives")
    
header()
ask_for_name()

while game_is_won == False and lives > 0:
    play()
    guess = input('Guess a letter or an entire word:')
    guess = guess.upper()

    if guess == word:
        game_is_won = True
        reveal = word
    elif len(guess) == 1 and guess in word:
        game_is_won = check_letter(guess, word)
    else:
        lives -= 1

    if game_is_won:
        player_won()
        print("WELL DONE")
    
    else:
        if lives <= 0:
            player_lost()
            print(f"YOU FAILED the word was: {word}")
        
    if game_is_won == True or lives <=0:        # Conditioned restart
        if restart_game() == True:
            game_is_won = False
            lives = 8
            reveal = list(len(word)*'_')
```

The key bits were adjusting some of the "if" tests to allow for life decrements, prompting for a name, prompting the menu, and restarts.

Here is a quick sample at the terminal.

```
-
_ _ _
You have 8 lives
Guess a letter or an entire word:Dog
Yea!
WELL DONE
Would you like to play again?Y/N/Q Q
```

Give those a try.

Comment: Amazing!! Thank you for the time spent looking over my code. After looking over your tweaked code, it all makes sense. Next time I will add more information to make it easier for the community to replicate my problem, many thanks again